# Modify nested arrays in JSON (Groovy)

Tags: json, groovy

I'm trying to parse and mofidy JSON with Groovy. Source JSON from REST API looks like:

```
[
   {
      "id":27858,
      "type":"ad",
      "stats":[
         {
            "day":"2021-01-21",
            "sex":[
               {
                  "impressions_rate":0.349,
                  "value":"f"
               },
               {
                  "impressions_rate":0.621,
                  "value":"m",
                  "clicks_rate":0.22
               }
            ],
            "age":[
               {
                  "impressions_rate":0.217,
                  "value":"18-21"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "day":"2021-02-25",
            "sex":[
               {
                  "impressions_rate":0.349,
                  "value":"f"
               },
               {
                  "impressions_rate":0.651,
                  "value":"m"
               }
            ],
            "age":[
               {
                  "impressions_rate":0.217,
                  "value":"18-21"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":565291,
      "type":"ad",
      "stats":[
         {
            "day":"2021-03-21",
            "sex":[
               {
                  "impressions_rate":0.78,
                  "value":"f",
                  "clicks_rate":0.33
               },
               {
                  "impressions_rate":0.551,
                  "value":"m"
               }
            ],
            "age":[
               {
                  "impressions_rate":0.17,
                  "value":"18-21"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

It's an array with some ids and data for them. I want to grab `id`, `day` inside `stats` array and elements from `sex` array. After all manipulations my JSON should be like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 27858,
    "day": "2021-01-21",
    "impression_rate": 0.349,
    "value": "f"
  },
  {
    "id": 27858,
    "day": "2021-01-21",
    "impression_rate": 0.621,
    "value": "f",
    "clicks_rate": 0.22
  },
  {
    "id": 27858,
    "day": "2021-02-25",
    "impressions_rate":0.349,
    "value":"f"
  },
  {
    "id": 27858,
    "day": "2021-02-25",
    "impressions_rate":0.651,
    "value":"m"
  },
  {
    "id": 565291,
    "day": "2021-03-21",
    "impressions_rate":0.78,
    "value":"f",
    "clicks_rate":0.33
  },
  {
    "id": 565291,
    "day": "2021-03-21",
    "impressions_rate":0.78,
    "value":"f",
    "clicks_rate":0.33
  }
]
```

So, the main goal is - loop through all `ids` -> elements in `sex` array (for each `id`) and add to these elements `day` and `id` mapped fields. I tried to start with empty map with inject, but after 1 hour of debugging i still can't achieve desired output, so maybe better to loop through existed values in array? But I can't even reach `sex` array.

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText '''...'''
List expected = json.inject([]){ r, e ->

    Map ids = e.findAll {
        k, v -> k == "id"
    }

    e.each{ k, v ->
    if( (v.any{ it.sex } ) 
        v.each{ r << ids + it }
    }
    return r
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have nested structures, that contain again nested structures,
a good option, to get a flat result, is to use `collectMany`; like
`collect` it transforms each item of the iterated container, but the
results gets concated.

E.g. you can `collectMany` on your outer data, then again on the
`stats`, and finally just collect over `sex`.

```
def data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse("data.json" as File)

println data.collectMany{ o ->
    o.stats.collectMany{ i ->
        i.sex.collect{ it + [id: o.id, day: i.day] }
    }
}
// [[impressions_rate:0.349, value:f, id:27858, day:2021-01-21], 
//  [impressions_rate:0.621, value:m, clicks_rate:0.22, id:27858, day:2021-01-21], 
//  [impressions_rate:0.349, value:f, id:27858, day:2021-02-25], 
//  [impressions_rate:0.651, value:m, id:27858, day:2021-02-25], 
//  [impressions_rate:0.78, value:f, clicks_rate:0.33, id:565291, day:2021-03-21], 
//  [impressions_rate:0.551, value:m, id:565291, day:2021-03-21]]
```

Comment: Nice one! What if I want to iterate through `age` array? I mean how to bring same functionality without repeating code above and do smth based on input parameter like `String field = age/sex`.  For age it will be `i.age.collect`  Will be cool to loop like this: `i.needed_field.collect`. I tried with String param but it didnt work.

Comment: @ChokkiAST `i.sex` is just short for `i["sex"]` or `i.get("sex")`. This way you can parameterize it.

Comment: Good to know this things!